# Expression is not an integer constant expression

Tags: c++, xcode, blender

I am using xcode 4.2.1, Apple LLVM compiler 3.0.

Project cleans successfully in xcode and builds successfully from the command line. The problem is the project fails to build in xcode.  I feel like I am missing something in my xcode configuration.  I have made no edits to the original source I pulled down.

**From the log navigator:**

```
CompileC /Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/source/blender/blenkernel/Blender.build/Debug/bf_blenkernel.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/idcode.o source/blender/blenkernel/intern/idcode.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Developer/Code/blender-build/blender
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-return-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 "-DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -D__SSE__ -D__MMX__ -D__SSE2__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -DOPJ_STATIC -DGLEW_STATIC -DWITH_AUDASPACE -DWITH_BULLET -DWITH_OPENEXR -DWITH_TIFF -DWITH_OPENJPEG -DWITH_DDS -DWITH_CINEON -DWITH_FRAMESERVER -DWITH_HDR -DWITH_AVI -DWITH_QUICKTIME -DWITH_PYTHON -DWITH_PYTHON_SECURITY -DWITH_MOD_FLUID -DWITH_SMOKE -DWITH_LZO -DWITH_LZMA -DWITH_GAMEENGINE -DWITH_LIBMV -DFFTW3=1 -DWITH_INTERNATIONAL -DWITH_FREESTYLE -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/lib/Debug/include -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenkernel -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenfont -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenlib -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenloader -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/gpu -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/ikplugin -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/imbuf -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/makesdna -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/makesrna -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/bmesh -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/modifiers -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/nodes -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/render/extern/include -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/guardedalloc -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/iksolver/extern -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/memutil -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/mikktspace -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/raskter -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/smoke/extern -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/libmv -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/atomic -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/windowmanager -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/audaspace/intern -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/rigidbody -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/avi -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/quicktime -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/python -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/intern/elbeem/extern -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/glew/include -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/bullet2/src -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/lzo/minilzo -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/lzma -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/extern/recastnavigation -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/lib/darwin-9.x.universal/fftw3/include -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/source/blender/blenkernel/Blender.build/Debug/bf_blenkernel.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/source/blender/blenkernel/Blender.build/Debug/bf_blenkernel.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/lib/Debug -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Winit-self -Wnonnull -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -msse2 -msse -pipe -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/source/blender/blenkernel/Blender.build/Debug/bf_blenkernel.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/idcode.d -c /Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/idcode.c -o /Developer/Code/blender-build/cmake/source/blender/blenkernel/Blender.build/Debug/bf_blenkernel.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/idcode.o
```

**Error:**

```
/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/idcode.c:90:10:{90:10-90:29}: error: expression is not an integer constant expression [3]
     int i = ARRAY_SIZE(idtypes);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Developer/Code/blender-build/blender/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_utildefines.h:353:36: note: instantiated from:
     ((sizeof(struct {int isnt_array : ((void *)&(arr) == &(arr)[0]);}) * 0) + \
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What can I do to get a clean build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded xcode to version 4.6.3.  The compiler updated to LLVM 4.2 and these problems were resolved.  Otherwise I don't know why the previous version was failing.